# Python overload operator =

Tags: python, operator-overloading

I have requirement in Python that, When I do this kind of code

```
class B(): pass
A = B # not really assign value, but to invoke a function to do some work.
```

I want to invoke other function when do assignment "A = B", so I think about operator overloading, I found a link for this:

> http://thepythonguru.com/python-operator-overloading/

But it seems we cannot overload the operator "=", is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Don't do this, using operators to produce side effects doesn't sound like an awesome idea to me.

Comment: The language exposes no way to do this directly. You would have to hack together something. It sounds highly inadvisable.

Comment: You cannot:  assignment is not "an operator" in Python.  Assignment is a kind of _statement_ instead.  You can no more change what an assignment statement does than, e.g., you can change what a `return` statement does.